# Explicitely setting quote level colours for filetype mail in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

In my system wide `mail.vim` syntax file for vim there are six quotation levels defined. However, it seems that there are only two different colours used alternately for even and odd levels. Is there a way to assign unique colours for all six levels?

Comment: Just [set different colors](https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes/blob/master/colors/southernlights.vim#L74-L79). Or [like this](https://gist.github.com/MicahElliott/720355/356bc8d7b417bc38b3393d330f903daac45e3228#file-adobe-vim-L133).

Comment: @phd Thanks, that works. Much easier than I thought considering the complicated stuff in mail.vim

Answer (score 3):

The default syntax script (`$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/mail.vim`) exposes six highlight groups for six quote levels:

```
mailQuoted1
mailQuoted2
mailQuoted3
mailQuoted4
mailQuoted5
mailQuoted6
```

but they are linked in a funky way to other highlight groups and to each other, which is why you get that alternating pattern:

[image: original]

You can style those highlight group individually, though, as per `:help colorscheme-override`:

```
" in your vimrc
augroup my_colorschemes
    autocmd!
    autocmd Colorscheme * highlight mailQuoted1 ctermfg=red
        \ | highlight mailQuoted2 ctermfg=green
        \ | highlight mailQuoted3 ctermfg=yellow
        \ | highlight mailQuoted4 ctermfg=magenta
        \ | highlight mailQuoted5 ctermfg=cyan
        \ | highlight mailQuoted6 ctermfg=blue
augroup END
```

[image: custom]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file `~/.vim/after/syntax/mail.vim` that modifies the system highlight groups. This file could look like this:

```vim
hi link mailQuoted1     Comment
hi link mailQuoted2     Identifier
hi link mailQuoted3     Special
hi link mailQuoted4     Statement
hi link mailQuoted5     Type
hi link mailQuoted6     PreProc
```

The names on the right hand sides are the highlight groups you want to link to. You can see them all by issuing `:hi`. Pick any six different ones you like and put them in the file.

All of this is documented in `:help :highlight`.